# What are the IA-32 Keywords?

Tags: assembly, x86

What are the IA-32 Keywords? What are the restrictions for label names? I'm currently writing assembly code in the AT&T Syntax - Bonus: I'm not even sure what the difference between Intel and AT&T Syntax is.

Edit: I'd mostly like to know which restrictions there are no labels, for example, is `print` a allowed label name?

```
print:
pushl %eax
pushl $str
call printf     # output contents of stack according to out string
popl %eax       # Clean up the stack, remove the parameters of print
jmp end
```

Comment: This question is a little vague. Also, I would advise against starting with AT&T syntax, it is by far the most confusing of the two, especially memory operands.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the standard given to us by the University - I also have no idea why they choose the AT&T Syntax.

Comment: @wowpatrick, the distinction is IMO a philosophical question how you approach it. Intel uses the formulaic/mathematical approach and from this it follows that `targt = value` while other CPUs seem to use a more language oriented approach where you can say `Move the Value to the Target`. Many of the older popular CPUs used this, while Intel made it's own. With this in mind it makes it a bit easier, but it's still confusing when switching between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restrictions you are talking about are assembler parser specific, so without telling which assembler you are using, you can not answer this question in a meaningfull way. 
For masm a general guide is that you use `@@`  for local labels and a label may not start with a number. Other assemblers use similar rules, but not neccessarily or they may vary in details.

The main difference between Intel and AT&T Syntax is that the assignment is reversed. Intel uses

```
 mov    eax, value   ;  eax = value
```

and AT&T uses

```
mov    value, %eax   ; Move value to eax.
```

Obviously there are more to it, but this is way to broad for answering here, so I recommend reading the manuals or google.

For a start you can look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax to find a bit more.

Comment: I'm using gcc to compile the assembly code on a x86 linux target. Thanks for the link to the wikipedia article, I only had a look at the IA-32 page, which is quite small.

Comment: gcc is only a frontend, so it uses probably nasm.(?) When you compile a C code to asm you can add  `-masm=intel` to get the assembler output in Intel syntax. However, I don't think that nasm can deal with that though. Not sure as I don't use nasm myself. If you write the assembler by yourself then you should look at some tutorial for nasm. It's also helpfull if you write a simple C program and look at the output what gcc creates.

Comment: @Devolus: gcc uses gas. And in nasm, you can use intel syntax by switching it on using .intel_syntax. And when looking at gcc produced assembly with gdb, you can switch it on using -diassassblyr intel (gdb command line). But maybe I misread your comment. :)

Comment: -disassembly-flavor intel. Curse you, phone. :)

Comment: @gnometorule, you read it right. That'S why I put a question mark behind it anyway, as I was not sure. :) IT's definitely nice to know that GDB and GAS can also work with Intel syntax. :)